# Any way to know if a variable is an angularjs promise?

Tags: angularjs

I'm making a directive that takes a function as a scope parameter (`scope: { method:'&theFunction' }`). I need to know if the result returned by that method is an angular promise (if yes something will happen on resolution, otherwise it happens right away).

For now I'm testing if `foo.then` exists but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use `$q.when` to wrap the object as a promise (whether it is or not).  Then, you can be sure that you are always dealing with a promise.  This should simplify the code that then handles the result.

Documentation for `$q.when` is [here with $q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q).

Comment: That seems an excellent idea. The only (minor) issue I would have with it would be that it would require to inject $q just for this.

Comment: In that case, you could make it so the method you are calling always returns a promise.  (Again, by using `$q.when`.  Then any caller will know to expect a promise.

Comment: I'd still prefer having the dependency on $q rather than "forcing" the function to return a promise. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This answer will definitely work, but there is a way to know if a variable is an angularjs promise without guaranteeing that it will be by adding overhead and a dependency.

Comment: Good tip, but not an answer to the original question.

Comment: Still I do not get it. If the value was not promise, then successCallback gets called instantly?

Comment: successCallback should get the value containing the value you provided to the when function, this means you can write the same code no matter if its promise or not.

Answer (score 81):

Angular's `when()` is a good option as Davin mentioned.

If that doesn't meet your needs then Angular's [internal way of checking](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d653607162488839b440de7b00b3c00d360bca3a/src/ng/q.js) (it uses this inside `when`) is very close to what you're doing:

```
var ref = function(value) {
   if (value && isFunction(value.then)) {
      // Then this is promise
   }
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I'm doing in fact. Thanks for finding that in the source, I had a look but must have skipped over it.

Comment: In my opinion this answer is superior to the currently accepted answer by Davin Tryon; because the language of the question is "Any way to know if a variable is an angularjs promise" and this answer shows exactly how to know; the accepted answer merely works around the need to answer the question.

Comment: Although it's (semi) important to note that this isn't actually checking whether the object is a promise, it's checking if the object has a `then` property which happens to be a function.

Comment: The actual check is more like:
`(isObject(value) || isFunction(value)) && isFunction(value.then)`

Comment: if you don't want to write your own isFunction function, Lodash and Underscore each have their own versions

Answer (score 5):

@kayakDave, thanks for guiding to right place.

[angular $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

> ```
> when(value, [successCallback], [errorCallback], [progressCallback]);
>             Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a $q promise. 
>             This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might  or might not be a promise, 
>             or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.
> ```

```
$q.when(value).then(function (data) {
//this helps me to bind data from $resource or $http or object
}
```

check this  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremylikness/Q2jMG/)

Comment: I'm not sure to see how relevant to the original question your answer is. Could you elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

The `$q.when()` answer seems like the best answer for most use cases, I used **instanceof** for mine.

```
    if(buttonData instanceof $q) {
        buttonData.then(function(actions) {
            $scope.buttonActions = actions;
        });
    } else {
        $scope.button = buttonData;
    }
```

Alternatively, the following **IF** worked as well, but I ended up going with the above solution.

`if(Object.getPrototypeOf(buttonData) === $q.prototype) {`