# Check if object is a promise in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There are cases when I need to check if an object is a promise or not, e.g. to show a loading indicator when getting initial data from an API which might take a couple of seconds.
So far I'm using this code snippet:

```
if ($scope.data.$resolved === false){
   // data is a promise as it is not resolved yet
}
else{
   // data is not a promise as it either never was or has been resolved
}
```

This seems to work well but since I'm not an Angular expert (yet) I was wondering if there's a better / recommended way to check if an object is a promise. Thanks!

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723735/any-way-to-know-if-a-variable-is-an-angularjs-promise) is a nice post that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know, if the promise is already resolved. If you pass your callback into the  `.then`, this code will be executed, even if the promise is already resolved.

And it seems like a bad practice make your method return 2 different types.

A promise or the data directly.

Just always return a promise, even if the data is fetched from the cache. 
Pass it into the `.resolve`, where ever the data did come from.

Something like this:

```
function getData(){
 var data = getFromCache();
 if( data ) {
   var deferred = $q.defer(); //Make your own promise
   deferred.resolve(data);
   return deferred.promise;
 }else{
   return $http.get("someData.json")  //Return the promise from the `$http.get`
     .then(function(data){
        return data;
      });
 }
}
```

Comment: Why all the cruft? `return $q.when(getFromCache() || $http.get("someData.json"))`