# How to check if object is promise in Angular unit tests?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-promise

I want to have an assert that checks if the returned object from calling a method is a promise.

Is it enough to check if it exists and has a `then` method?
Or is there a better way of doing this since having a `then` method doesn't guarantee the object is a `$q` deferred promise?

EDIT:
The question is not duplicate of "[Any way to know if a variable is an angularjs promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723735)".
The solution for that question is to ensure that a promise is returned using `$q.when()`.
I'm asking how to know that an object is a promise, not how to make it one if it isn't.

Thanks.

Comment: real question would be : why do you need to check if result is a promise ? $q.when() allow to handle both promise and non promises objects, isnt that your need ?

Comment: I want to check that a method returns a promise as part of a test, e.g. `it('should return a promise',...)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to know if a variable is an angularjs promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723735/any-way-to-know-if-a-variable-is-an-angularjs-promise)

Comment: The titles are similar, but the accepted answer is not applicable for the unit testing scenario I described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to do this directly.
When constructing objects, i normally do it like this:

```
function Derp(){
   this.constructor = Derp;
}
Derp.prototype.method = function(){};
```

So that I can:

```
expect( new Derp() instanceof Derp ).toBe(true);
```

but in both $q.promise and $q itself, there are no constructor or prototype properties except for the constructor property in their __proto__ (in chrome) objects; and even those just point to JavaScripts' fundamental Object.

So in order to test that something is a promise, you have to make the assumption that the object you're returning is a promise based on its' other properties:

```
expect(typeof result.when).toBe('function');
expect(typeof result.then).toBe('function');
```

I don't like it either, but that's the only way I can think of to do this.